# Basic Python- Multiplying a given numbers by consecutive numbers

Tags: python-3.x

How to write Python script that can read a list of user input
numbers and displays each number times a number increment from 1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will have a better chance of getting answers if you post some code demonstrating that you have attempted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer from comment

```
def mult_func(s):
num_lst = s.split(',') # Split the user input into a list by comma ( , )
    # enumerate generates an integer relevant to the number of iterations starting at 0
    # eg. 1st num, i = 0, 2nd num, i = 1, 3rd num, i = 2, etc
    for i, num in enumerate(num_lst):
        value = float(num)*(i+1)
        print('{0} x {1} = {2}'.format(float(num), (i+1), value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The user entered numbers have to be separeted by commas ( , )
    mult_func(input('Enter a list of numbers: '))
```

Comment: Thank You for the help! it helps a lot. But what i meant was  for example, a user inters a number(n)  then n * 1 = <the result of multiplication>, 
n * 2 = <the result of multiplication>, n * 3= <the result >  n*4, n*5 
and so on